# How to disable Thunderbird quit when <ctrl> + <W> pressed?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

Is there a way to disable Thunderbird quit when <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> pressed?

Comment: Have you tried the KeyConfig extension?
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension

Comment: Have you looked at his? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts#w_customizing-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: @Ynhockey it sounds like that is what I'm searching for. But I don't understand, how to add this extension to Thunderbird? Extension Manager don't find anything relevant.

Comment: @Ynhockey thank you, I found the way and posted the answer with full instruction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is based on @Ynhockey comment:

This could be done using [Keyconfig extension](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension).

Once Keyconfig couldn't be installed with standard Extension Manager, follow this instruction:

- [Download](http://mozilla.dorando.at/keyconfig.xpi) and save the extension file to your hard disk.
- In Mozilla Thunderbird, open Add-ons from the Tools menu.
- From the options button next to the add-on search field, select "Install Add-on From File..." and select the downloaded add-on.
- Restart Thunderbird and use the add-on installed to disable any keyboard shortcut you want.

Comment: An updated version of `Keyconfig` now exists, called  `Dorando keyconfig`. It can be installed directly from the add-ons manager.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to install addons or change keys.

In Thunderbird config you have something like `mail.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab`.

Set this to `false` -> restart TB -> should works *( tested on TB 60.6.0 (32bits), Win 7 )*

How to get to this setting area? Here is the doc -> https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/config-editor

This is better idea beacuse CTRL+W will still works for close another tabs

Comment: Perfect; thank you. Didn't even have to restart :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here the official Thunderbird answer:

> Some (but not all) keyboard shortcuts can be customized using an
>   add-on. This can also be useful to disable certain shortcuts, for
>   example to prevent unexpected behavior from single-key shortcuts.
>
> **Dorando Keyconfig** (an updated version of the original "keyconfig") and **Menu Wizard** are examples of add-ons that help to customize or
>   disable shortcuts.
>
> (Note that third-party add-ons are not supported or endorsed by Mozilla.)